# Integrating the product of two normal pdfs

Tags: integration, probability-distributions

I have been working on some problems on Gaussian processes and came across the formula
$$
    \int \mathcal{N}\left(a ; Bc, D\right)\mathcal{N}\left(c; e, F\right) dc = \mathcal{N} \left(a; Be, D+BFB^T\right),
$$

where the densities are multivariate normal and vectors/matrices are of the appropriate size. It's not that clear to me (without getting into messy algebra) where this is coming from. Does anyone have a reference for this result?

Comment: Can you prove the result in the univariate case? That might help you see where the general (multivariate) case comes from.

Comment: If you want a probabilistic interpretation of this equality, note that the given is the (marginalized) pdf of the r.v. $A$ where $A\ |_{ C=c} \sim \mathcal N(Bc, D)$ and $C \sim \mathcal N(e,F)$.